# Action Listener error

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

I keep getting an error when I implement the ActionListener. I dont really understand how to fix it. I did the actionPerformed (ActionEvent ev) {} and put my login button to call it with lg.addActionListener(this);

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.Event.*;
import java.applet.Applet;

public class LoginScreen extends JApplet implements ActionListener   {
    JTextField un;
    JPasswordField pw;
    JButton lg;
    JLabel user,pass;

    public LoginScreen () {
        un = new JTextField ();
        pw = new JPasswordField ();
        lg = new JButton ("login");
        user = new JLabel ("username");
        pass = new JLabel ("password");

        lg.addActionListener(this);

        this.setLayout(null);

        user.setBounds(10, 10, 120, 20);
        pass.setBounds(10, 30, 120, 20);
        un.setBounds(140, 10, 200, 20);
        pw.setBounds(140, 30, 200, 20);

        lg.setBounds(140, 55, 100, 20);

        this.add(user);
        this.add(pass);
        this.add(un);
        this.add(pw);
        this.add(lg);

        this.setSize(500, 300);
        this.setVisible(true);
        }       
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {

    }
}
```

Comment: So what is the error?

Comment: First bad practice  `setLayout(null)`  2nd) implements ActionListener in a top level class, 3rd) Not add @Override annotation in `actionPerformed()` 4th) Your method implementation is empty..

Comment: 1) Java GUIs might have to work on a number of platforms, on different screen resolutions & using different PLAFs.  As such they are not conducive to exact placement of components.  To organize the components for a robust GUI, instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556), along with layout padding & borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17874717/418556). 2) `this.setSize(500, 300);`  An applet's size is set in HTML.  It should not be set in code. ..

Comment: .. 3) Why code an applet?  If it is due to spec. by teacher, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should stop teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/). 4) Always copy/paste error & exception output.

Answer (score 5):

Change `import java.awt.Event.*;` to `import java.awt.event.*;`

Java is case-sensitive.

Also change `import java.applet.Applet;` -> `import javax.swing.JApplet;`

Answer (score 4):

You have the wrong imports. You need. `import java.awt.event.*;` or

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
```

The latter is better practice

---

If you're using one of the following IDEs (with default configuration), this is easily fixed with a couple buttons.

Eclipse <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>

Netbeans <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>

Comment: @Josh Enselma It wasn't that fast. I just copied and pasted the code and I spotted the error fairly quick. I actually a pretty slow typer compared to others. I'm still have to look at the keyboard a lot of times :)

Comment: @peeskillet you have to look? i don't believe you

Comment: Since he has `import java.awt.*;` , he can just remove the faulty ones?

Comment: @Xbit, `java.awt.*` doesn't import `java.awt.event.*`

Comment: @peeskillet i see, it uses more then only java.awt.

Answer (score 2):

```
import java.awt.Event.*;
```

needs to be

```
import java.awt.event.*;
```

This causes a compile error. Once this has been fixed, you need to write some code in the actionPerformed or nothing will happen when you button is pressed.

Comment: +! I think the OP knows the second part. Besides there isn't even a `main` to run the program, so I think the question was just an example duplicating the error :)

Comment: Thanks, I also upvoted yours! I admit you beat me to the answer first, second time that has happened to me today..so frustrating haha. I agree that he most likely knows about the second part, however, you never know based on some of the questions I have seen on SO :)

Comment: thanks this helped me a lot. case sensitivity always gets me.

Comment: Not a problem, consider accepting an answer so that this question is resolved on stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

In your actionPerformed method, if you do not specify any action, your button will do nothing.